# using filter css property ruins the layout on IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, layout, filter, gradient

wanted to have a gradient BG for my menu without having to use a background image
IE "support" gradients via it's filter property

open the following jsbin example on IE to view and play with it http://jsbin.com/ijudu4/9/edit
in IE7 the list can't break from it's container.

on IE8 it is working, but when you add z-index to the container(to solve other IE7 issues)
the list is also not visible

my "solution" for now is just using a background image, will be happy to find a better one

Comment: The questin is - why would you use such horrible hacks, that IE filters are? Better go with something that at least is not vendor-specific, or specific for "actual browsers" - they are supporting CSS3 ihn which you can left IE and do something "the right way".

Comment: +1. Totally agree with Tomasz Kowalczyk. The use of filters is not recommended.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to recommend using [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com) instead of `filter` to get IE to do gradients (and border radius).

CSS3Pie is a very clever little hack for IE which allows you to use a more standards-compliant method for setting these properties.

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion,and i will look into this Pie,  but i would really want to understand/solve this problem with the filter - already "solved" it with a bg image

Comment: @Avi Pinto - glad you solved it. An image isn't an ideal solution but it does the job. CSS3Pie is great because it doesn't use any images, and allows you to use a proper CSS solution for every other browser.